# Puzzled with NSPredicate predicateWithFormat table

Tags: objective-c

both lines of code work but not as I would expect. The first one, using a variable skips only the first item of the table and updates all the remaining items. Using a string literal in the second option doesn't and works the way I want. Why is this happening??

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"myString == %@", date];

                                    OR

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"myString == '5/24/14'"];
```

Comment: Okay, so you haven't shown what `date` is, you haven't shown how you're using this predicate, and you expect to get help? You're concealing almost everything about what you're doing - we're supposed to just guess?

Comment: You're right, I'll bear that in mind next time but the code was just too messy as I'm just testing what works and what doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

To see why this is happening, try logging `date`:

```
NSLog(@"%@", date);
```

You will see that the resulting string (in the console) does not look at all like `'5/24/14'`! But that (what you see in the console) is the string that you are using in your first code.

So it's all about *how* the NSDate is covered to an NSString. How to get around this? Use an NSDateFormatter to convert the date to a string in the form you're after!

Comment: Yes, I've done it and date in the console is '5/24/14'! I'm using NSDateFormatter to get the string and ignore the time.

Comment: I'm trying to update the results of the table but when I use date, it updates all the items in the table but the first one.

Comment: @binaryZomby Does your `date` string include the enclosing single quotes? You don't want those; they're part of the string literal syntax for NSPredicates.

Comment: date is actually an NSString parameter. I must be doing something really silly, since it works the way I need after the top item is displayed on the table view.